# Restrict permission "write to disk" of a particular user

Tags: permissions

I am a new user inexperienced.

I want to restrict permission "write to disk" of a particular user, without affecting the primary user "root" .

My particular user is called "vdesktop" and of type "administrator".

I heard about the "chomd" but I do not know how to implement it.

I just want a user "vdesktop" has permission to read and run the program, write permissions blocked

Answer (score 1):

The command you are referring is [chmod](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod)

Setting the following mode 755 will allow read/execute access only to any user, who is not the owner of the file.

If user `vdesktop` should execute a specific file which is owned by other user (e.g. root) the following command should answer your needs:

```
sudo chmod 755 /path/to/file_name
```

Note: `sudo` will cause `chmod` to be execute as `root`

Comment: Users "vdesktop" have some problem causing loss of memory space, temporary files appear in the / tmp and for a long time it makes my memory space becomes narrow. I really don't want it that way

Can i use it as ??

sudo chmod 755 / tmp

Comment: running ` sudo chmod 755 / tmp ` will cause the entire` /tmp` folder to be write-able only to `root` - this might break a lot of functionality (you don't want it)

Comment: I think that's it all I need
Thanks, I think the issue has been resolved.

Comment: @cosiup - did my answer help you solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, Thanks you so much, Yaron !  the issue resolved